# What are different types of Rishis?

Tags: sadhana, rishi

The types I know are Maharshi, Devarshi, Rajarshi, Bramharshi.

- What is the difference among them?
- What is their chronology?
- Who awards/grants them those titles?
- What kind of sadhana/practice needs to be observed to conquer each of these stages?
- Are those titles permanent?

Comment: See answer [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11931/5091). Full hierarchies (7) list of the ṛṣis were covered there.

Answer (score 5):

**Maharshi** 
 a Rishi who is very great in his spirituality(great seer), who had reached a 
certain level towards his goal(path).

**Rajarshi** 
 a King who is so spiritual that he becomes a Rishi.

**Devarshi** 
 a Rishi dwelling in the heavenly regions or a deva who is also a Rishi. The sons of Dharma or Yoga, divine or godlike sage.

**Brahmarshi** 
 a Rishi who has seen the Supreme Spiritual Truth and who were the founders of gotras of Brahmans or caste-races.