# Caste system from the perspective of vedic astrology

Tags: caste-system, astrology

It can be argued that the caste system is equivalent to Ricardo's theory of comparative advantage (1817), but instead of looking at advantages in supply chain management, technology, logistics, etc., vedic astrology looks from the perspective of human personality traits, in the form of planets in signs in houses or nakshatras or both.

Considering that most people's birth chart is a mix of Deva/Manushya/Rakshasa, Artha/Dharma/Kama/Moksha, and Sattva/Rajas/Tamas, how can it be that any 1 person is purely Brahmin, Kshatriya, Vaisha, or Shudra?

What was the formula used to calculate this?

Comment: related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29075/12304

Comment: Caste is based on ancestry.

Comment: Brahmins are sattvic, turiya, purest, filled with soma, prana, sahasrara chakra, kshatriyas have physical masculine energy, strong build, rajasic, along with vaishyas in upper Chakras, meanwhile lower Castes are tamasic beasts filled with negative energy, ghosts, evil spirits, in patala Chakras, equal to any malicious evil wild beast which can't even control its sense organs. In what is called human body, there are various levels of existence from God, siddha, humans etc to lowest worms.

Comment: Yes, caste is based upon ancestry, but I know of a Brahmin family, where different children did different things.
Majority followed parents' traditions and married Hindus and within caste.
1 person went to US and married a white girl.  He comes back to India, shows off his wealth, and acts superior.
1 person married a Muslim, converted to Islam, wears burqa, and does Namaz 5 times per day.
1 person married a Sudra.
I do not have their birth charts, but would you guess that only people with 51% (or more) Deva, Dharma/Moksha, and Sattva would continue their family tradition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do Sruti texts mention either or both of birth-based varna and guna-based varna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31859/do-sruti-texts-mention-either-or-both-of-birth-based-varna-and-guna-based-varna)