# Isn't the varna determined, by the Vedic varnashram, by birth?

Tags: vedas, varna, shudra, varnashrama, upanayanam

As far as I know, ***varnashram*** is originally a Vedic idea, by which ***Shudras*** that were **N**ot recognised as ***dvija*** were Not entitled for ***Upanayana*** that usually used to take place at the age of 8-11 years of the boys fathered by ***dvija*** males. From this, it evidently follows that by the Vedic ***varnashram***, people were born with their ***varna***. Still, I've heard some people claim that the ***varna*** of guys was **N**ot determined by their birth in Vedic times. Nevertheless, so far I haveN't heard them say any substantial stuff in defence of their claim.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31859/do-sruti-texts-mention-either-or-both-of-birth-based-varna-and-guna-based-varna

Comment: Not entitled is misleading. By all logic if the wrong Varna does a ritual it has no effect, good or bad, so there is no reason a Shudra can't do it, it just wouldn't do anything. This is clearly the case as no repercussions or checks are listed for doing the ritual with the wrong Varna. The only reason scriptures advise against it is because they want to warn you against wasting time and resources. If you want to do it anyway, no one is going to stop you.