# Are Ursa Major and Ursa Minor associated with Jambavan and Jambavati astrologically?

Tags: astrology, yuga, astronomy

Astrologically/astronomically, Are Ursa major correspond/associated with jambavanta, Ursa minor with jambavati, because both being bear constellations, and Vega, Pole star of dwapara Yuga, krishna respectively?

Comment: This question is too complex in nature and fit to be posted in any astrological site,  in my opinion.   Even if someone with astrological knowledge provides proper answer,  will the moderators be in a position to understand the answer? @Aoi.T_015

Answer (score 2):

[Polaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polaris) keeps on shifting and shifting of polaris star leads to change in Yuga

> Because Polaris lies nearly in a direct line with the Earth's
>   rotational axis "above" the North Pole—the north celestial
>   pole—Polaris stands almost motionless in the sky, and all the stars of
>   the northern sky appear to rotate around it. Therefore, it makes an
>   excellent fixed point from which to draw measurements for celestial
>   navigation and for astrometry. The moving of Polaris towards and, in
>   the future, away from the celestial pole, is due to the precession of
>   the equinoxes.[19] The celestial pole will move away from α UMi after
>   the 21st century, passing close by Gamma Cephei by about the 41st
>   century, moving towards Deneb by about the 91st century. The celestial
>   pole was close to Thuban around 2750 BC,[19] and during classical
>   antiquity it was closer to Kochab (β UMi) than to Polaris

Basically, earth's rotation axis is changed to rotate about different constellation, when Yugas change. Current Polaris is Dhruva of Ursa minor/Little Dipper linked with Kaliyuga and surrounded by Draco/Dragon constellation. People are short lived and of weak stature.

In Satyuga(Brahmin dominates), Polaris is Deneb(Hamsa/Cygnus constellation). Even today, the highest spiritually ascended person is called Paramhans(The Greatest Swan).

> SB 11.5.21 — In Satya-yuga the Lord is white and four-armed, has
>   matted locks and wears a garment of tree bark.
>
> SB 11.5.23 — In Satya-yuga the Lord is glorified by the names **Haṁsa**,
>   Suparṇa, Vaikuṇṭha, Dharma, Yogeśvara, Amala, Īśvara, Puruṣa, Avyakta
>   and Paramātmā.

In Tretayuga(Kshatriya dominates), Polaris is Vega(Lyra constellation/Lion constellation). Earth is ruled by powerful kings during Tretayuga. Hence, Ram avatar born in Treta Yuga was a powerful king.

In the Srimad Bhagavatam, Krishna tells Arjuna, that among the Nakshatras he is [Abhijit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abhijit), which remark indicates the auspiciousness of this constellation.

In Dwaparyuga(Vaishya dominates), Polaris is Cepheus(Vrishparva/Cow-Sheep herd constellation). Earth is ruled by people involved in business. Hence, Krishna avatar born in Dwapara yuga was a cow heard in young age.

[Pole Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_star)

> The precession of the equinoxes takes about 25,770 years to complete a
>   cycle. Polaris' mean position (taking account of precession and proper
>   motion) will reach a maximum declination of +89°32'23", which
>   translates to 1657" (or 0.4603°) from the celestial north pole, in
>   February 2102. Its maximum apparent declination (taking account of
>   nutation and aberration) will be +89°32'50.62", which is 1629" (or
>   0.4526°) from the celestial north pole, on 24 March 2100.[8]
>
> Precession will next point the north celestial pole at stars in the
>   northern constellation Cepheus. The pole will drift to space
>   equidistant between Polaris and Gamma Cephei ("Errai") by 3000 AD,
>   with Errai reaching its closest alignment with the northern celestial
>   pole around 4200 AD.[12][13] Iota Cephei and Beta Cephei will stand on
>   either side of the northern celestial pole some time around 5200 AD,
>   before moving to closer alignment with the brighter star Alpha Cephei
>   ("Alderamin") around 7500 AD.[12][14]
>
> Precession will then point the north celestial pole at stars in the
>   northern constellation Cygnus. Like Beta Ursae Minoris during the 1st
>   millennium BC, the bright star closest to the celestial pole in the
>   10th millennium AD, first-magnitude Deneb, will be a distant 7° from
>   the pole, never close enough to be taken as marking the pole,[9] while
>   third-magnitude Delta Cygni will be a more helpful pole star, at a
>   distance of 3° from celestial north, around 11,500 AD.[12] Precession
>   will then point the north celestial pole nearer the constellation
>   Lyra, where the second brightest star in the northern celestial
>   hemisphere, Vega, will be a pole star around 13,700 AD, though at a
>   distance of 5° from celestial north
>
> The celestial pole will then return to the stars in constellation
>   Draco (Thuban, mentioned above) before returning to the current
>   constellation, Ursa Minor. **When Polaris becomes the North Star again
>   around 27,800 AD**, due to its proper motion it then will be farther
>   away from the pole than it is now, while in 23,600 BC it was closer to
>   the pole.[citation needed]
>
> **> Over the course of Earth's 26,000-year axial precession cycl**e, a
>   series of bright naked eye stars (an apparent magnitude up to +6; a
>   full moon is −12.9) in the northern hemisphere will hold the
>   transitory title of North Star

Yuga motion in the period of 24,000 years is also explained by Guru of Paramhans Yogananda, [Sri Yukestswar Giri](http://www.dwapara-yuga.org/), who was also well versed in astrology and astronomy.

> After 12000 years, when the sun goes to the place in its orbit which
>   is farthest from Brahma, the grand center (an event which takes place
>   when the autumnal equinox is on the first point of Libra), dharma the
>   mental virtue, comes to such a reduced state that man cannot grasp
>   anything beyond the gross material creation. Again, in the same
>   manner, when the sun in its course of revolution, begins to advance
>   toward the place nearest to the grand center, dharma, the mental
>   virtue, begins to develop ; this growth is gradually completed in
>   another 12000 years.
>
> Each of these periods of 12000 years brings a complete change, both
>   externally in the material world, and internally in the intellectual
>   or electric world, and is called ne of the Daiva Yugas or Electric
>   Couple. Thus, in a period of 24000 years, the sun completes the
>   revolution around its dual and finishes one electric cycle consisting
>   of 12000 years in an ascending arc and 12000 years in a descending
>   arc.
>
> From 11501 BC, when the Automnal Equinox was on the first point of
>   Aries, the sun began to move away from the point of its orbit nearest
>   to the grand center toward the point farthest from it, and accordingly
>   the intellectual power of man began to diminish. During the 4800 years
>   whiche the sun took o pass through one of the Satya Couples or 4/20th
>   part of its orbit, the intellectuof man lost altogether the power of
>   grasping spiritual knowledge. During the 3600 years following which
>   the sun took to pass through the Descending Treta Yuga, the intellect
>   gradually lost all power of grasping the knowledge of divine
>   magnetism. During the 2400 years following, while the sun passed
>   through the Descending Dwapara Yuga, the human intellect lost its
>   power of grasping the knowledge of electricities and their attributes.
>   In 1200 more years the sun passed through the Descending Kali Yuga and
>   reached the point in its orbit which is farthest from the grand center
>   ; the Automnal Equinox was on the first point of Libra. The
>   intellectual power of man was so much diminished that it could no
>   longer comprehend anything beyond the gross material of creation. The
>   period around AD 500 was thus the darkest part of Kali Yuga and of the
>   whole cycle of 24000 years. History indeed bears out the Indian rishis
>   , and records the widespread ignorance and suffering in all nations at
>   that period.
>
> The position of the world in the Dwapara Sandhi era at present (AD
>   1894) is not correctly shown in the Hindu almanacs. **The astronomers
>   and astrologers who calculate the almanacs have been guided by wrong
>   annotations of certain Sanskrit scholars (such as Kulluka Bhatta) of
>   the dark age of Kali Yuga is 432000 years, of which 4994 hae (in AD
>   1894) passed away, leaving 427006 years still remaining. A dark
>   prospect ! and fortunately one not true.**
>
> The mistake crept into almanacs for the first time aboout 700 BC
>   during the reigh of Raja Parikshit, just after the completion of the
>   last Descending Dwapara Yuga. At that time Maharaj Yudhishtira,
>   noticing the appearance of the dark Kali Yuga, made over his throne to
>   his grandson, the said Raja Parikshit. Maharaja Yudhishtira, together
>   with the wise men of his court, retired to the Himalaya Mountains, the
>   paradise of the world. Thus there was none in the court of Raja
>   Parikshit who could understand the principple of correctly calculating
>   the ages of the several Yugas.
>
> Hence, after the completion of the 2400 years of the then current
>   Dwapara Yuga, no one dared to make the introduction of the dark Kali
>   Yuga more manifest by beginning to calculate from its first year and
>   to put an end to the number of Dwapara years.

Ursa Major has Big Dipper, Ursa words mean Rishi(one who sees) or Sages, hence refer to the Saptrishis or 7 Sages, whose Gotras are running on earth.