# Formula for calculating Kaliyug

Tags: kali-yuga

Every generation will look at the bad things in society and say that "Things were good when I was young.  Things are bad now, because we are living in kaliyug."

What is the formula to calculate the beginning and end of kaliyug?

Comment: You can go through this article  (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_Yuga)@DAN BHATT

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35411/16530

Comment: Not everything is bad now health has improved, poverty reduces and we are finding sustainable sources alternatives for energy. Actually, lots of things have improved.