# Are there any vedic statements saying that one can be called brahmin by behavior

Tags: scripture, vedas, brahmins

There are some people who keep claiming that one can be called brahmin by karma and give the reference of Yaksha Prashna in which Yudhishtra talks about brahmin-hood and claims that brahamana hood does not depend on birth.

Is there any reference in Vedas which explicitly mentions this claim?

Comment: So you want answer from vedas only?

Comment: Related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29075/12304

Comment: yes only from vedas but not from any EPICs.

Comment: Then try to rephrase the title.

Comment: Listen, O Yaksha! It is neither birth, nor study, nor learning, that is the cause of Brahmanahood, without doubt, it is **behaviour** that constitutes it. One's behaviour should always be well-guarded, especially by a Brahmana.  https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03311.htm

May be you used karma instead of behavior

Comment: Changed the title.

Comment: @TalkisCheapShowmeCode: The Veda definitely talk about dwija - twice born.  However, it does not indicate brAhmanas, as commonly believed.  It indicates one who got REALISATION.  Veda mantras are cryptic and should be understood in an esoteric manner only.

Comment: Do you want the answer only from the Vedas or any Hindu scripture will do?

Comment: Only Vedas. If its possible.