# Questions on Varna System

Tags: scripture, vedas, caste-system, varna

Can You Tell Me Some Verses From Hindu Scriptures Which Say Varna Is Not Based On Birth?

Comment: Do you agree with the closure of your Q? If not then please post a comment here pinging me. Since I have a scripture Gold badge my single vote closed it :(

Comment: As per me yours is a duplicate of this Q --- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17859/4732

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 verses that clearly say that Varna is not dependent on birth in an endogamous group.

> Yudhisthira said, " In human society, O mighty and highly intelligent
> serpent, it is difficult to ascertain one's caste, because of
> promiscuous intercourse among the four orders. This is my opinion. Men
> belonging to all orders (promiscuously) begat offspring upon women of
> all the orders. And of men, speech, sexual intercourse, birth and
> death are common. And to this the Rishis have borne testimony by using
> as the beginning of a sacrifice such expressions as -- of what caste
> server may be, we celebrate the sacrifice. **Therefore, those that are
> wise have asserted that character is the chief essential requisite.
> .... whatsoever now conforms to the rules of pure and virtuous
> conduct, him have I, ere now, designated as a Brahmana.**'

**(Mahabharata Aranya Parva Section CLXXIX)**

> Maheshwara said, ‘..**Neither birth, nor the purificatory rites, nor
> learning, nor offspring, can be regarded as grounds for conferring
> upon one the regenerate status. Verily, the conduct is the only ground.**
> All Brahmanas in this world are Brahmanas in consequence of conduct. A
> Sudra, if he is established on good conduct, is regarded as possessed
> of the status of a Brahmana. The status of a Brahma, O auspicious lady
> [Uma], is equal wherever it exists. Even this is my opinion. He,
> indeed, is a Brahmana in which the status of Brahma exists – that
> condition which is bereft of attributes and which has no stain
> attached to it. of human beings in four orders dependent on birth is
> only for purposes of classification. **The boon giving Brahma, when he
> created all creatures, himself said that the distribution of human
> beings in four orders dependent on birth is only for purposes of
> classification.'**

**Mahabharata Anusasana Parva Section CXLIII**

Answer (score 1):

चातुर्वर्ण्यं मया सृष्टं गुणकर्मविभागशः।

तस्य कर्तारमपि मां विद्ध्यकर्तारमव्ययम्।।4.13।।

The four varna were created by me based on Guna-karma(intrinsic aptitude i.e. what you do), however even though I am the cause of that intrinsic aptitude, know that I am without agency.

This is from Shreemad Bhagvat Gita Chapter 4, shlok 13.