# Was Kanada a Rishi?

Tags: rishi, kanada

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanada_(philosopher)) wiki article describes *Kanada* as both a sage and a philosopher. Was he a *Rishi* or a mere philosopher?

Comment: According to wikipedia he is sort of  philosopher and Inventor or Theoretical Physicist.

Comment: @Yogi: As always, I find wiki less trustable by the day :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. He was indeed a ṛṣi. But what kind of a ṛṣi was He? What was his expertise? From [that wiki article you mentioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanada_(philosopher)), it's obvious Kaṇāda pioneered the [Vaiśeṣika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaisheshika#Literature_of_Vaisheshika) vāda school, one of the [Ṣaḍ Darśanas | 6 major Philosophies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dar%C5%9Bana) in *Hinduism*. Nevertheless, due to his (exalted) rank he was that of a seer, hence the prefixed title of « Maharṣi » to his name Kaṇāda i.e., He is addressed (and famous) as Maharṣi Kaṇāda.

Now, let me throw some light on the various level of ṛṣis. Ratna Kośa <sup>[A]</sup> & TriKāṇḍaŚeṣa (now extinct; from the whatever scattered quotes of them we have from the various vedic literatures) list 7 level of Ṛṣis which are being enumerated in their decreasing order of greatness as follows:

Deva-Born (= not of human origin):

① Brahmarṣi i.e., born from Brahmā e.g. Brahmarṣi Vasiṣṭha<sup>[B]</sup> <sup>[C]</sup>

② Devarṣi i.e., born out of Deva e.g. Devarṣi Nārada Muni

Human-Born:

③ Maharṣi, the greatest of all ṛṣis who are of human race.

④ Paramarṣi, slightly below than Maharṣi

⑤ Kāṇḍarṣi, dealing with a certain Kāṇḍa — Chapter — of a Śāstra or Wing e.g., Jaimini (Mīmāṁsā propounder)

⑥ Śrutarṣi, one of the best preceptors of Śāstra

⑦ Rājarṣi, last and least in merit e. g., Viśvāmitra, Ṛtuparṇa, King Janaka

References:

> <sup>[A]</sup> **Ratna Kośa** -
>
> sapta brahmarṣi devarṣi maharṣi paramarṣayaḥ । 
> kāṇḍarṣiśca śrutarṣiśca rājarṣiśca kramāvarāḥ ॥ 
>
> <sup>[B]</sup> [Viṣṇu Purāṇa B1: 7.5](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp041.htm) 
> <sup>[C]</sup> Vāyu Purāṇa Vol. 1, 9.62

Comment: Vishwamitra is a Brahmarshi.

Comment: @sv.: I think the argument that he pioneered that Vaisheshika school, one of the Shatdarshanas is solid enough. Did not look at that aspect before.

Comment: @vinayasisya: Thanks, that helped. You could add references to support the classification that you mentioned and I will accept the answer.

Comment: @sv. Didn't I give the 2 sources where these ṛṣi definition come from? I haven't got hold of these original kośa, which means I don't have access to the original exact sanskrit verses. That's a different thing. But what I have provided is authentic.

Comment: Vishwamitra attained the status of Brahmarshi.

Comment: @sv.  I don't have more than this. I did cite my sources though (i.e., Ratna & TrikāṇḍaŚeṣa kośas), from where such views originate although I still don't have the ślokas off hand since that work is extinct. Maybe in some universities archives they might be having a copy there...

That was part of my notes which I thought to share in an attempt to shed light about this since such information is not really public (i.e., only restricted within scholars) and this was passed onto me in due course of my learning, which I thought to share.

Comment: @AmitSaxena: Read above, my reply to sv. This should answer some of your questions too.

Comment: @sv. Also, coming to your other correction: because Viśvāmitra was born out of human race who also ruled as a King, hence I [including many scholars] classified him under Rājarṣi when we talk about genealogy. Otherwise, that « Brahmarṣi  » title he possessed (with time) was an acquired-one, all these only to surpass over Brahmarṣi Vasiṣṭha (Historical purāṇādis considered the latter to be his rival, all this due to ego), not natively.  Sree Charan is right i.e., Viśvāmitra attained that status (with time) which means He isn't one of Brahma putras by default.

Comment: @vinayaśiṣya Ok. You can quote from or link to Vishnu Purana [here](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/index.htm). Look for Vāyu Purāṇa in [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9095/2995). Maybe you can also take a look at my question [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8881/2995).

Comment: @vinayaśiṣya No problem, I will fix it :)

Comment: @vinayaśiṣya I also saw that you have joined the Sanskrit SE proposal. Would love to chat with you here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39073/discussion-on-sanskrit-se-proposal

Comment: @vinayaśiṣya Go the link that I have mentioned in the above comment. When you reach there, tag me in the chat using the "@" symbol